# How to use UI Tests with DotNetBar components?

Tags: c#, winforms, ui-testing, white-framework, dotnetbar

I'm trying to test user interface of WinForms application that contains DotNetBar components (ButtonItem, i.e.). But i can't get access to inherited elements. ComboBox in the ButtonItem.
I've tried Teststack.White and FlaUI tests. Coded UI can't even catch any action because i use Win 10 Creators Update.

Comment: You would need to check if the UI widgets are identifiable using standard tools like Inspect.exe, FlaUInspect or UISpy.

Comment: @Ashish, i've checked it by VisualUIAVerifyNative. I found only a button there, but it also should contains a combobox (ButtonItem).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the DotNetBar does not correctly implement the UIA providers and therefore tools like FlaUI or White and Coded UI do not see the correct controls.
Make sure that neither UIA2 nor UIA3 can show the nested elements (best is with FlaUInspect in admin mode to be sure).
If that does not see the elements, you won't be able to find them. Reach out to the creator of DotNetBar and tell them they should implement the UIA providers correctly.